# Confused about 民国 dates on receipts

Tags: calendar

I have been in Taiwan for about two weeks.  Some of my shopping receipts have [民国](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar) dates, some have Gregorian, and some have both. What I find confusing is that when there is both, the **day** is not always the same on both. And I have at least two receipts with the same 民国 date but the Gregorian dates differ by two or more days.

Answer (score 1):

民国 (Republic of China) era starts from 1912. Therefore, just add 1911 to the 民国 year number and you'll know the Gregorian year number. For example, 民国106年(ROC Year 106)=1911+106=2017 A.D.

Sometimes, 民国 is omitted for simplicity. To distinguish ROC year from Gregorian year, follow this rule:

If a year number is relatively small (no matter whether it's larger than 100), it's an ROC year number. (Therefore, 98年 (Year 98) is not Year 1998, it's Year 2009).

The above rule only applies to daily life, not for academic use. However, the date of the year **should remain the same** on both ROC date system and Gregorian date system. If you see differences, it must be produced by "magic" reasons rather than different date systems.

Comment: I repeat: the DAY was different.  However, I think I figured it out.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have noticed that you say the day was different.

Comment: And I edited the question to make it plainer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.  What I **thought** was the day in the 民国 date was **not** the day.  The ones with the apparent discrepancy were showing the 民国 **months** of a lottery system.  I did not know about the lottery at the time, so when I saw three numbers, I interpreted them as year, month, day.  But actually, it was year and two different months:

**107**年**01-02**月

The numbers were more prominent than the 汉字 and so I thought I was seeing the second day of the first month, when it actually refers to the lottery cycle of the first and second months.

Comment: Easy way to tell is Asian dates are given in Y M D, so the number in the middle wouldn't be date.

Comment: The number in the middle, as I said, _wasn't_ in the middle.  It was _two_ months at the end.  A _range_ of months in a format the looked like month-day.

Comment: *I know* what it is. And no, the format doesn't look remotely like "month-day", because the last number is followed by the word "month". I'm pointing out that since the last number is clearly marked as the month, and we know from the Y/M/D format that the middle number can't be the day, it's intuitive to conclude that it's a range of months - as is obvious.

Comment: I repeat: because the numbers were made much more prominent than the hanzi, it made me think of 107-01-02.  You can say “doesn’t look remotely like,” but obviously it wasn’t remote enough for me, or this question would never have been asked.

Comment: I fully understand that you were mistaken, there's no need to keep repeating the obvious. But again, a number followed by the character "month" means... month, not day. You can either accept this simple, intuitive rule for the future, or keep being defensive about getting it wrong, it's no skin off my back either way.